# JPA / Hibernate Many to Many with associated columns and nullable join column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have three tables setup using PostgreSQL 9.4.5.  Some details removed.

```
Table: component
id | bigint | not null default nextval('component_seq'::regclass) |

Table: file
id | bigint | not null default nextval('file_seq'::regclass) |

Table: component_file
id           | bigint | not null default nextval('component_file_seq'::regclass) |
component_id | bigint | not null    |
file_id      | bigint |             |
usage        | text   | not null    |
```

Essentially, it's a many-to-many relationship with additional columns in the many-to-many join table.

1. A file can be associated to one or more components.
2. A component can be associated to one or more files.
3. It is possible for a component to be associated with no files which is why the component_file.file_id is nullable.

I have modeled this using JPA with Hibernate as my implementation provider.   I use OneToMany associations (Component and File) in order to have access to the associated join table metadata and two ManyToOne associations for the join table object representation (ComponentFile)

```
public class Component {
  ...
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "component_seq")
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updateable = false)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "component", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<ComponentFile> componentFiles;
  ...
}

public class File {
  ...
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "file_seq")
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updateable = false)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "file", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<ComponentFile> componentFiles;
  ...
}

public class ComponentFile {
   ...
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
   @JoinColumn(name = "component_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updateable = false)
   private Component component;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
   @JoinColumn(name = "file_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true, insertable = true, updateable = false)
   private File file;
   ...
}
```

All is working fine except I have indeterminite insert order.

If I insert a component without a file (1 component row and 1 component_file row), the persistence is fine.

If I insert a multiple components associated to a single file (1 component row, 2 file rows, 2 component_file rows), then an error occurs because Hibernate is inserting a component_file row with a null file_id reference.  This causes a constraint violation due to a unique constraint as Hibernate is inserting two rows with the same component id and NULL file id which is not allowed (unique constraint on component_file.component_id where component_file.file_id IS NULL).

```
2016-01-26 10:59:30,506 ERROR [SqlExceptionHelper] - Batch entry 1 insert into component_file (usage, component_id, file_id, id) values ('INCLUDED', '180', NULL, '202') was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
2016-01-26 10:59:30,506 WARN [SqlExceptionHelper] - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
2016-01-26 10:59:30,507 ERROR [SqlExceptionHelper] - ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uidx_component_file_component_id" Detail: Key (component_id)=(180) already exists.
2016-01-26 10:59:30,509 ERROR [BatchingBatch] - HHH000315: Exception executing batch [could not execute batch]
2016-01-26 10:59:30,512 INFO [DbConstraintNameRetriever] - Constraint name retrieval results [Name: uidx_component_file_component_id | Original class: java.sql.BatchUpdateException | Message: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uidx_component_file_component_id" Detail: Key (component_id)=(180) already exists. | Postgres exception?: true | Batch update exception?: true].
```

Why is this occurring and what is the workaround or alternative methods for solving this type of relationship and persistence?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }
```

for Component and File @ManyToOne annotations in ComponentFile.

Comment: This was the root cause of my issue... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have specified `mappedBy` attribute in the `OneToMany` annotation, make sure that you are also setting the other end of the relationship by calling `ComponentFile.setComponent(...)` or `ComponentFile.setFile(...)` appropriately whenever you are adding `ComponentFile` to the arrayList in `Component` or `File` entity.

If you still see the same error or if you are already doing it, posting the Entity creation and association logic would help.